# How does TCP's slow start handle a send rate below network capacity?

Tags: tcp, congestion-control, tcp-slow-start

I'm working on a UDP-based project that requires congestion avoidance. After studying the algorithms used by TCP (example sources [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5681) and [here](https://intronetworks.cs.luc.edu/current/html/reno.html)), I have what I believe is a *reasonably* compliant implementation of the slow start and congestion avoidance states of TCP Reno. However, while testing I have observed the following surprising behavior:

1. Say the sender opens a new connection, and sends data at a constant and sufficiently slow rate such that no packets or acknowledgements are dropped. In slow start, a typical sender will increase `cwnd` by the number of new acknowledged bytes for each acknowledgement that it receives (see [RFC5681, section 3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5681#section-3.1)). Thus, in this scenario, `cwnd` will increase linearly without bound.
2. After some time has passed, say the sender suddenly has a trove of data to send. If a sufficient amount of data has already been sent at that slower rate, `cwnd` will be much larger than the true network capacity, and the sender will flood the network with packets.

Considering how much effort has been put into avoiding such floods, I don't think this is the intended behavior. Have I overlooked something?

---

*Idea 1*: Idle conditions will cause the sender to restart in slow-start, but this is generally avoidable so long as the sender does not wait more than 1 RTO between packets (see [RFC5348, section 4.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5681#section-4.1)). Furthermore, RTO should be rounded up to 1 second (see [RFC6298, section 2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6298#section-2)), and so this mechanism can be circumvented by sending one small packet every half second.

*Idea 2*: TCP Friendly Rate Control ([RFC5348](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5348#section-4.3)) has a notion of "data-limited intervals", and TFRC has been designed so as to mirror the behavior of TCP. I suspect there might be special behavior related to TCP being data-limited, as opposed to congestion-window-limited (part 1 is an example of such a scenario), but I have yet to find such behavior defined anywhere.

Comment: This question is not about programming. It seems to be more appropriate for [networkengineering.se].

Comment: I see. I thought algorithms were still appropriate here. Can it be moved or does it need to be closed?